# Wordpress Gallery: Remove <br /> tags with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tags

I am trying to remove `<br />` tag from wordpress native gallery through jquery and have tried lots of way but none of them works..

I have tried few codes below (note: I have changed in my theme file `<br style="clear:both" />` to `<br class="clearboth" />` also I have deregisterd jquery and registed with googleapis for my theme.

```
<script>$('br.clearboth').html();</script>
```

and

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $.strRemove = function(theTarget, theString) {
        return $("<br/>").append(
            $(theTarget, theString).remove().end()
        ).html();
    };
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I am placing this code exactly at the top of the entry div of the wordpress. May be I am placing script at wrong place. Nothing working and none of this removing any br tag from gallery section...

Actual source code I am getting as below..I have tried js as you guyz said but its not working somehow you can see in source code the  is still there.

```
<!--BEGIN: Single Post-->
    <article class="post-866 gallery type-gallery status-publish hentry mp_gallery" id="post-866">

        <div class="entry">

        <!--[this js i have added here]-->
        <script>
            $("br.clearboth").remove();
        </script>


            <style type='text/css'>
                #gallery-1 {
                    margin: auto;
                }
                #gallery-1 .gallery-item {
                    float: left;
                    margin-top: 10px;
                    text-align: center;
                    width: 33%;
                }
                #gallery-1 img {
                    border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
                }
                #gallery-1 .gallery-caption {
                    margin-left: 0;
                }
            </style>
            <!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php -->
        <ul id='gallery-1' class='gallery galleryid-866 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail clearfix'><li class='gallery-item'>
                <p class='gallery-icon'>
                    <a href='http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0432.jpg' title='DSC_0432'><img width="190" height="110" src="http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0432-190x110.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail colorbox-866" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet," title="DSC_0432" /></a>
                </p>
                    <p class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                    </p></li><li class='gallery-item'>
                <p class='gallery-icon'>
                    <a href='http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0503.jpg' title='DSC_0503'><img width="190" height="110" src="http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0503-190x110.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail colorbox-866" alt="Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium" title="DSC_0503" /></a>
                </p>
                    <p class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium
                    </p></li><li class='gallery-item'>
                <p class='gallery-icon'>
                    <a href='http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0516.jpg' title='DSC_0516'><img width="190" height="110" src="http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0516-190x110.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail colorbox-866" alt="DSC_0516" title="DSC_0516" /></a>

                </p></li>

                <br class="clearboth" />

                <li class='gallery-item'>
                <p class='gallery-icon'>
                    <a href='http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0657.jpg' title='DSC_0657'><img width="190" height="110" src="http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0657-190x110.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail colorbox-866" alt="Most beautiful face evern catched before" title="DSC_0657" /></a>
                </p>
                    <p class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                    Most beautiful face evern catched before
                    </p></li><li class='gallery-item'>
                <p class='gallery-icon'>
                    <a href='http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0658.jpg' title='DSC_0658'><img width="190" height="110" src="http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0658-190x110.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail colorbox-866" alt="Beauty queen on the earth and praising pain was born and But I must explain to you how all this" title="DSC_0658" /></a>

                </p>
                    <p class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                    Beauty queen on the earth and praising pain was born and But I must explain to you how all this
                    </p></li><li class='gallery-item'>
                <p class='gallery-icon'>
                    <a href='http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0676.jpg' title='DSC_0676'><img width="190" height="110" src="http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0676-190x110.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail colorbox-866" alt="Handsome Guy will Look after you :)" title="DSC_0676" /></a>
                </p>
                    <p class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                    Handsome Guy will Look after you :)
                    </p></li>

                    <br class="clearboth" />

                    <li class='gallery-item'>

                <p class='gallery-icon'>
                    <a href='http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0677.jpg' title='DSC_0677'><img width="190" height="110" src="http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0677-190x110.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail colorbox-866" alt="Dashing Guy who is looking for a gal" title="DSC_0677" /></a>
                </p>
                    <p class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                    Dashing Guy who is looking for a gal
                    </p></li><li class='gallery-item'>
                <p class='gallery-icon'>
                    <a href='http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0125.jpg' title='DSC_0125'><img width="190" height="110" src="http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0125-190x110.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail colorbox-866" alt="DSC_0125" title="DSC_0125" /></a>
                </p></li><li class='gallery-item'>

                <p class='gallery-icon'>
                    <a href='http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0416.jpg' title='DSC_0416'><img width="190" height="110" src="http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0416-190x110.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail colorbox-866" alt="One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin." title="DSC_0416" /></a>
                </p>
                    <p class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                    One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. 
                    </p></li>

                    <br class="clearboth" />

                    <li class='gallery-item'>
                <p class='gallery-icon'>
                    <a href='http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0431.jpg' title='DSC_0431'><img width="190" height="110" src="http://localhost/mediatuts/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSC_0431-190x110.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail colorbox-866" alt="DSC_0431" title="DSC_0431" /></a>
                </p></li>

                <br style='clear: both;' />
            </ul>

    </article>

    <!--END: Single Post-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to remove br tags from the DOM, you can do this:

```
$("br").remove();
```

If you only want of a specific class, do this:

```
$("br.clearboth").remove();
```

If you only want to remove br tags from a specific node, do this:

```
$("#someId br.clearboth").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Please read my comment above on Jasper's answer also see my edited question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wow its done. The problem was as wordpress may be generating id and class dynamically so if I place js above the container it wasn't identify as it was reading js first than the gallery tags. so I place the script after gallery tags and it works fine. Thanks a lot for your support. for me `$("br.clearboth").remove();` works fine.

Answer (score 3):

It's not very clear what your code currently does but you can remove `br` elements from the DOM like this:

```
$('br').remove();
```

You can target `br` elements in a specific container like this:

```
$('#container-id').find('br').remove();
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YtedC/

Comment: I have tried all yours and Daniel's code but none of them working... You can see I have edited my question and added source code I am getting after adding js as you guys said. I also would know you that the <br/> tag is generating by wordpress Gallery and it is not hard coded into html. Is that the reason or id doesn't matter? Even I can't use any specific Gallery ID to find `<br/>` tag as id is dynamically generated. I have tried in static html but still not working.. is that google-apis causing the issue?

Comment: Alright! its done and I gave vote you both. I really appreciate your help..But the code I have used is from Daniel so I will select his answer. Thanks again